# How to convert a single quote string to a double quote string in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string

My query is how can i convert an array of strings arr = ["mumbai", "bangalore"] to an array of single quoted strings in ruby on rails like arr = ['mumbai', 'bangalore']

Comment: In your source code?

Comment: Yes! in my source code

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Because semantically both versions are equivalent in this example: `"mumbai" == 'mumbai' #=> true`

Comment: I guess the question is nothing to do with Ruby/RoR it's about a tool that you use to write your code.

Comment: @ArshpreetSoodan : Do you think of code transformation? Input is your existing Ruby program where Strings are denotated with single quote, output is a program where Strings are written with double quotes?

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible, because those quotes are not there. Strings are objects held in the memory and quotes are just a way to define a new strings. Once defined, it is stored in the memory as a collection of characters and has no information on how it was created.

However, ruby `inspect` method will always wrap the string in double quotes when it is displayed in the console to make it clear we deal with a string object. It is important to understand that this is only for display and that those quotes are not part of the string itself

```
# Every way of creating a string creates identical object in the memory
> "hello"
=> "hello"

> 'hello'
=> "hello"

> %{hello}
=> "hello"

# But quotes are not part of that object
> puts "hello"
hello
=> nil
```